# Using local reference on jquery function or this? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which solution is better?

```
var handleDateChange = function () {
            var dateBtn = $('#dateBtn');
            dateBtn.on('changeDate', function () {                
                var dateValueStr = dateHelper.getFormattedDate(dateBtn);
                dateBtn.text(dateValueStr);
                $.when(//Something is running)
                    .done(function () {
                            dateBtn.DoSomething();
                    });
                dateBtn.datepicker('hide');
            });
        };
```

When we use `dateBtn` variable it always searching element by id again?
Or better solution is using in some places `$(this)`:

```
var handleDateChange = function () {
                var dateBtn = $('#dateBtn');
                dateBtn.on('changeDate', function () {                
                    var dateValueStr = dateHelper.getFormattedDate($(this));
                    $(this).text(dateValueStr);
                    $.when(//Something is running)
                        .done(function () {
                                dateBtn.DoSomething();
                        });
                    $(this).datepicker('hide');
                });
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
var dateBtn = $('#dateBtn');
```

the search for elements is immediately made, and it won't be done again. So caching the jQuery object is efficient.

But you don't really need this caching, unless you verified you have a performance problem. Using `$(this)`, assuming it's the same element, would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The `$(this)` version is much better because it is more flexible and reusable. Using the first method is undesirable because the code is tightly coupled to the `dateBtn` variable.

Consider if you come back to the code in future and want to assign the event handler to other elements, not just `dateBtn`. Using the first method, you'd have to either change all `dateBtn` to the `this` method, or duplicate the whole code and use a different variable. Using the `this` method, all you would have to do is call the exact same code on the additional elements.

The differences in performances can be considered negligible because `$(this)` is not re-selecting the element, it is adding the jQuery wrapper around the existing plain DOM element. This is easily resolved by storing the jQuery object in a variable like below, and refering to `$this` instead of creating a new jQuery object over and over:

```
$this = $(this);
```

Side note: your second code still refers to `dateBtn` in the promise, so it is still dependant on the `dateBtn` variable. To resolve that you can create a closure and pass the target object.